# Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 2.4.8 64-bit - Weird Desktop Crash

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, cinnamon

This crash thing is happining third time for me. I solved the last two by a refresh install of mint, formatted I mean. Nothing special happened when I was using the computer, than I shut it down. By the morning I pressed power button and booted to Linux Mint, this happened again. I really want to know what is going on? Is it only my computer, because I have friends running the same system.

My computer is a Lenovo IdeaPad z510 with Nvidia GT740M, I use the driver recommended by the system. All the other things are at default settings. Also I have a Windows 8 beside Mint. Is it possible to be a reason for this. Thanks in advance, if more information needed beside the screenshot, I can put it down here.

Also my shortcuts and bios function buttons (these volume and brightness like buttons) are not working. Can not read the text like in terminal, all darken out.

[image]

Comment: How is that a crash? Looks like it is only the terminal crashing.

Comment: @sikerbela it used to look like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KYj0e.png . And with the same theme and settings it became this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ktzb.png . After shutting down the night before I just started, entered my login password, waiting longer than before to came up, and this is happened.

Comment: Are there any error messages in tty1?

Comment: I can't see one.